# New code coverage metrics not returning values from SonarQube 5.3 API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-web

I need to fetch unit test coverage data for new code changes via the api. The metrics. I can see the data in SonarQubeDashboard but the api is not returning any values for the metrics like:

1. new_coverage
2. new_line_coverage
   (etc)

I am invoking the api :

https:///api/resources?format=json&metrics=ncloc,line_coverage,new_line_coverage

Even the Public Nemo Instance does not return these metric values:

https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?format=json&metrics=ncloc,line_coverage,new_line_coverage,new_coverage

The above API is returning only ncloc and line_coverage for each and every project.

Please dont tell me to check if these metrics are not available in the version. They are, if you invoke the API:

https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/metrics/search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The modern way (api/measures/component)

SonarQube's `api/resources` Web API [is deprecated](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/resources), you should use `api/measures/component` instead (since 5.4).

Using [this project](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/overview?id=org.sonarsource.php%3Aphp) as an example:

> https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/measures/component?componentKey=org.sonarsource.php%3Aphp&metricKeys=ncloc,line_coverage,new_line_coverage,new_coverage&additionalFields=metrics,periods

#### The old way (api/resources)

If you're really stuck with `api/resources` (e.g. old SonarQube version), then keep in mind that for *new* metrics there is a notion of time delta (*new* since when ?), so you have to add `includetrends=true` to your request. Let's do that with your example:

> https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?format=json&metrics=ncloc,line_coverage,new_line_coverage,new_coverage&includetrends=true

This gives you `new_coverage` and `new_line_coverage` (for the projects which do have coverage and SCM information available).

Comment: We have version 5.3 so will have to use the old way. In that, have a question. The response has fields like var1, fvar1,; var3 and fvar3. What are the differences between var1, var3,.. etc?

Comment: `var1` is the value for the first period (`p1`), `fvar1` is the formatted value. `var2` is the value for period `p2` etc.

Comment: @Nicolas Is there a way to determine an individual file full 'componentKey' value via the UI? I have a faily complex project multi-module maven project and can't seem to determine the correct key for a specific java files. Thanks